# Fourier series convergence in $L^2(-\pi,\pi)$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I've got a proof in my course of the fact that Fourier series converge in $L^2(\pi,\pi)$. But, since $L^2(-\pi,\pi)$ is a Hilbert space with the scalar product $\left<f,g\right>=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f\bar g$ and that $\{e^{inx}\}_{n\in\mathbb Z}$ is an orthonormal basis, don't we have that $S(f)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}a_ne^{inx}$ where $a_n=\left<f,e^{inx}\right>$ converge in $L^2(-\pi,\pi)$ by definition ?

Comment: It's easy to see that $\{e^{inx}\}$ is an orthonormal system. The fact that it actually is a basis (i.e. it is complete) is usually a consequence of the result you found a proof for. Are you sure that at that point of your course you already new that it's a _basis_? If you do know that then it follows, in fact, that the Fourier series converges (in the $L^2$ -norm) to $f$ if $f\in L^2$.

Comment: @Thomas: Thank you. You right, we didn't proved this result, that's why we can't use it.